# Check iOS deployment target of a static library

Tags: ios, testing

I have many static libs like `libBlah.a`
With `file` tool I can check supported architectures. (arm64 or i386)

Is there tool to check `iOS Deployment Target` of the static lib?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `otool` to inspect the library file. With some experimentation I found that the flags `-lv` gave me useful output. Open up a terminal window and switch to the directory your library is in:

```
cd /path/to/parent/directory
```

(Hint: you can drag the icon from the title bar of a finder window into the terminal and it will enter the path for you). Then type the following command:

```
otool -lv myStaticLibrary.a | less
```

In `less`, type <kbd>/</kbd> (search) and then `LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS`. You should see something like this:

```
Load command 1
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
  cmdsize 16
  version 7.0
      sdk n/a
```

The deployment target should be the value next to `version`.

Comment: Is .a file(Universal) made in latest version will worked in project deployment target (say 9.3 will work on 8.0 )?

Answer (score 11):

The target OS version is encoded in the LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS load command in the MachO header of the static library. You can see it via:

```
otool -l mylib.a | grep -A 3 LC_VERSION
```

Example output:

```
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
  cmdsize 16
  version 9.0
      sdk n/a
```

Answer (score -2):

have you tried using preprocess macros?

```
#if IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (iOS Deployment Target)
```

Comment: Is this a guess, an answer, or intended as a comment?  No matter what this is, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It is an attempt to help, my friend =) 
And "no matter what this is" I don't see a reason for you to be so grumpy. 
If it doesn't help, well, at least I tried.